# Are there any SEO implications to switching a parked domain to an addon domain

Tags: seo, parking

I have parked domain on my site that redirects to a sub-folder. When you navigate the the URL you get something that looks like;

```
www.mainsite.com/parked_domain/whatever_page.html
```

The site was initially set up like this because the webhost at the time charge an additional fee for addon domains so the above was seen as an acceptable compromise.

Now the site is on a new host and addon domains are free. I wanted to switch the set up using an addon domain so navigating to the URL looks like;

```
www.parked_domain.com/whatever_page.html
```

Would this impact anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I've never heard of something called "addon domain". To someone like me who owns 30+ domains, the first I'm hearing of it shouldn't be on this site. I believe you made a good choice in leaving the old hosting company as they were trying to charge money for a non-service. That being said... To the question at hand.

There should not be any adverse (on the contrary, actually) effects to removing the `parked_domain` part of your URL structure. What you should do however, is create 401 URL re-write's for each of your old pages, to the new ones. If any pages were in fact indexed, that is. You could do a quick check on this by googling: `site:www.yourdomain.com`

So `/parked_domain/whatever.html` should 401 to `/whatever.html`.

Comment: "Addon Domain" is a term that cpanel uses. I've never seen it used anywhere else, but I'm confused by your statement `the first I'm hearing of it shouldn't be on this site` and what that actually means and its relevance to the answer.

Comment: I just meant that for you to own your domain but unable to change the URL structure because of something called "addon domain", is crazy, and having been in this business for 10 odd years, I should have heard about it before even coming to this site. I confess that I have never used cpanel. I'm more of a .conf guy myself... It's just insane that you would be forced to run your site under that /parked_domain/ URL structure.

Comment: @geoken if my answer is a solution, please set a checkmark to it. If not, please further develop your question so that the community has a chance to answer

Answer (score 0):

The parked domains will gain a little more value in terms of hosting an actual page, before you had no pages hosted as it was a redirect. Your best way forward now would be to get a simple one page with content on the parked sites just so Google can age them and ultimately when you do get to use them your get good results.